# Using ksqldb query consumer has a transient consumer group id, No Offset is Stored

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have been trying to use ksqldb to filter messages at consumer's side, I always can consume messages then filter them before processing but I'm trying not to consume messages that aren't needed by my processor. This is why I'm thinking about using ksql.

But I have a problem that the processor might be restarted, and I want to be able to process any missed records that were inserted to the stream while the restart was being performed.

I was tracking consumer groups while my ksql consumer was up and I noticed a consumer group like that: `_confluent-ksql-ksql-trialtransient_transient_MYSTREAM_5059263532526545342_1687162531557`

```
GROUP                                                                                            TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                                                                                                                                        HOST            CLIENT-ID
_confluent-ksql-ksql-trialtransient_transient_MYSTREAM_5059263532526545342_1687162531557 myStreamTopic 0          88              88              0               _confluent-ksql-ksql-trialtransient_transient_MYSTREAM_5059263532526545342_1687162531557-f7a16fb8-b04a-4170-bdbd-2889e749803d-StreamThread-1-consumer-b307c2b5-0976-4a8c-85b9-2fa9831572ed /10.40.0.0      _confluent-ksql-ksql-trialtransient_transient_MYSTREAM_5059263532526545342_1687162531557-f7a16fb8-b04a-4170-bdbd-2889e749803d-StreamThread-1-consumer
```

this is - as mentioned in the consumer group id -  a transient consumer group id, and is removed from consumer groups once I stop consuming, and when I start consuming again it will create a new consumer group, which means that I won't be able to track lags or offset to continue consuming from the last consumed record.

Is there a way to set the group id to a non-transient one?

Comment: You need to create a new stream, not just select with a where statement

Comment: I tried to create a stream from the select query, and indeed the group id doesn't have transient. But I think I still need to consume the data from the new stream and I would be facing the same issue when restarting my consumer.

Comment: You'd create a consumer outside of ksql with a group id set. Then progress will be kept when you commit offsets